# I can't install gulp locally, error with \node_modules\ansi-regex

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp, installation

I'm trying to install Gulp on Windows 10, but i get an error installing it locally.

```
$ node -v
v9.10.1

$ npm -v
5.6.0
```

I installed Gulp globally:

```
$ npm install --global gulp-cli

$ gulp -v
CLI version 2.0.1

$ npm init
...
```

Now i try to install it locally but... :

```
$ npm install --save-dev gulp
npm WARN deprecated gulp-util@3.0.8: gulp-util is deprecated - replace it, following the guidelines at https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.11: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 for compatibility with current and future versions of Node.js
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 for compatibility with current and future versions of Node.js
npm WARN deprecated natives@1.1.2: This module relies on Node.js's internals and will break at some point. Do not use it, and update to graceful-fs@4.x.
npm WARN css-clase10@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN css-clase10@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! path C:\Users\Jose\Documents\Programacion\CSS desde 0\CSS-Clase10\node_modules\ansi-regex
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\Jose\Documents\Programacion\CSS desde 0\CSS-Clase10\node_modules\ansi-regex' -> 'C:\Users\Jose\Documents\Programacion\CSS desde 0\CSS-Clase10\node_modules\.ansi-regex.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Jose\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-03-30T14_43_45_408Z-debug.log
```

Any idea why i am getting this error.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, solved.

https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/issues/10826

The problem was Malwarebytes